# Python: can function be defined inside of another function's argument list?

Tags: python, function, argument-passing

Is there a way to achieve something like this in python?

```
another_function( function(x) {return 2*x} )
```

Comment: What does this code do?  If called as `another_function(9)` is `18` what is actually passed into `another_function`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
another_function( lambda x: 2*x )
```

To be clear: this is taking place when `another_function` is called, not when it is defined.

Comment: This gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: No typo -- thought question was about function definition time, whereas your answer is at function call time.

Comment: @EthanFurman the question was exactly about call time (doesn't the fact that the answer is accepted ring a bell?). The author has used *anonymous function* syntax from Javascript and other ecmascript-based languages.

Comment: Amazingly enough, not everybody speaks Javascript or other ecmascript-based languages (and unfortunately I've seen bad answers accepted); I've changed my vote, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def another_function( function=lambda x: 2*x ):
    print(function(10))  #an example
```

I'm not sure what happens with the example code you posted, but with the solution shown if you call `another_function` it will call `function(10)` and print 20.

More to the point, you cannot call `another_function(7)` and get `14` because `7` will get assigned to `function` and `7(10)' will get you`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.